# Logstash NaN Value Handling

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm having issues with logstash where it cannot work with NaN values.

```
[ERROR][logstash.codecs.json     ][main][] JSON parse error, original data now in message field {:message=>"Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow\n at ...}
```

I have multiple fields incoming NaN from the source of data. They are normally `float`, `int` but they also can be NaN. I've browsed the discussions on elastic's forum itself, I could not find any answer.

Especially this is the problem I am having that someone asked years ago but left without an answer:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/json-codec-dealing-with-nan-inf/138611

How can I allow logstash to work ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, like it says in the error?

My kafka_properties for logstash is below: I don't have any extra configuration change in .yml files. I'm using everything default.

```
input {
kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "MY_SERVER"
    topics => [
        MY_SOURCE_1,
        MY_SOURCE_2
    ]
    codec => json
    decorate_events=> true
}
}
filter {
  mutate{
    add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["MY_SERVER:9200"]
    data_stream=>"true"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with RAW data structure. To diagnose the issue I recommend you to update the logstash conf and check the incoming data format. Here is an example logstash.conf for you.

```
input {
  kafka {
      bootstrap_servers => "MY_SERVER"
      topics => [
          MY_SOURCE_1,
          MY_SOURCE_2
      ]
#      codec => json
      decorate_events=> true
  }
}
filter {
  mutate{
    add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
  }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```

I disabled to JSON coded in Logstash input part. Save this yaml and run the logstash on the terminal.

```
./bin/logstash -f /path/to/your/config/test.yml
```

Check the output on terminal, if it's not proper JSON you need to take care of the RAW data.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be JSON from most of the topics... There's just that some topics sending data with NaN. When I do what you say, I see everything is working, however on kibana, I just see the JSON in one "message' field, I can't really search by, or toggle the avaiable fields... Within java, we can handle those NaN fields with ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS for ObjectMapper. I was wondering if there's something like that in elastic.

Comment: So for instance, when I check it without the codec, the message output is this: `{
  "field1": 9.4,
  "field2": 0.0,
  "field3": NaN,
  "field4": NaN,
  "field5": NaN,
}`   But same time those fields could've been set in different message.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, `NaN` is not number and can't accepted as string because `""` is missing. The acceptable format is `true` or `null` or `false` or `"NaN"` (NaN with double quote)

Comment: If possible manipulate the RAW data before send to Kafka.